# Поведение оператора switch в java

Tags: java, switch

Почему меняется поведение оператора `switch` при различных способах инициализации управляющей переменной?

В первом случае, когда переменной сразу присваивается значение - `char a = '1';` - все работает как надо.

А во втором, когда значение получается через - `char a = (char) br.read();` - выполнение `case`'ов начинается со второго метода, т.е. я не могу указать путь к файлу( первый метод как-бы пропускается). В обоих случаях тип переменной char и выбор кейсов происходит правильно. В чем может быть причина?

```
package task5;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    private String pathToFile;
    private String dataToWrite;

     private void getFilePath(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
        try {
            pathToFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("getFilePath Error " + e);
        }
    }

    private void getDataToWrite(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
        try {
            dataToWrite = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("getDataToWrite Error " + e);
        }
    }

    private void writeToFile(String path, String data) {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path)) {
            fw.write(data);
            fw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("writeToFile Error " + e);
        }
    }

    private void readFromFile() {
        try (FileReader fw = new FileReader(pathToFile)) {
            int c;
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                c = fw.read();
                res.append((char) c);
            } while (c !=  -1);
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("FileReader Error " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String menu = "Выберите необходимое действие: \n" +
                        "1 - записать файл; \n" +
                        "2 - прочитать файл; \n";

        System.out.println(menu);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Выберите вариант.");
        Main m = new Main();
        //char a = '1'; все работает
        char a = (char) br.read(); //пропускается первый метод

        switch (a) {
            case '1':
                System.out.println("Введите путь к файлу.");
                m.getFilePath(br);
                System.out.println(m.pathToFile);
                System.out.println("Введите данные для записи.");
                m.getDataToWrite(br);
                System.out.println(m.dataToWrite);
                m.writeToFile(m.pathToFile, m.dataToWrite);
                break;
            case '2':
                System.out.println("Введите путь к файлу.");
                m.getFilePath(br);
                System.out.println(m.pathToFile);
                m.readFromFile();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой первый метод пропускается? Строчка "Введите путь к файлу." печатается?

Comment: Смотрели что выводится в `a`? мне кажется что `read` нужно приводить к числу, а не `char`, а то можно долго удивляться поведению, не соответствубщему вашим ожиданиям

Comment: Только что проверил -- у меня все работает. Switch показывает именно введенный вариант

Comment: Выбор кейса происходит правильно. Выводится строка "Введите путь к файлу." , а затем сразу выводится строка "Введите данные для записи.", таки образом нет возможности ввести путь к файлу.

Comment: Видимо, вы не вычитываете перенос строки

Comment: Вопрос, который вы задаете, не связан с вашей реальной проблемой -- она в чем-то другом. Поведение оператора `switch` зависит исключительно от значения переменной и никак не может зависеть от того, откуда это значение получено. Выясните, какой символ вы получаете из входного потока --  (например, до оператора `case` можно вывести на консоль сам символ и его код: `System.out.println(" a = " + a + " (" + (int)a + ")");`. Учитесь сами искать причину того, что программа работает не так, как вы ожидали. Это полезно, и для этого есть масса способов. И ещё, полезно в `switch` всегда иметь `default`.

Comment: Обнулите ``br`` перед передачей в ``m.getFilePath(br);`` или, что еще лучше, передавайте туда другой BufferedReader-объект.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы! Проблема решена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 char a = br.readLine().charAt(0);
```

read() вычитывает только один символ, в данном случае '1'. В остатке остается еще перенос строки. И когда вызывается  pathToFile = bufferedReader.readLine(), то проверяется осталось ли что-то в остатке если да, то выводим иначе ждем ввода.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
String a = br.readLine();
```